# How to import 'describe', 'expect' and 'it' into a typescript tests for IDE to not to highlight them

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor

Wrote some tests and everything successfully runs, but my IDE (webstorm) highlights `describe`, `expect` and `it` and says "cannot find name". I want to keep everythig clean and get rid of these, but have no idea how.

We use protractor and jasmine.

[image]

Some more of the script:

```
import {HomePO} from './pageobjects/home'
import {browser } from 'protractor'


describe('Smoke test', function() {

    it('should initialize', function() {
        let width = 320;
        let height = 568;
        browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
    });

    it('should open homepage', function() {
        HomePO.get();
        expect(HomePO.isCurrentPage()).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 10):

I was having the same problem and did:

```
 npm install @types/jasmine --save-dev
```

and that solved it - no need to import anything from jasmine.

Comment: Thanks - that helped me. But eww - doesn't that mean all the Jasmine functions (describe, it, ...) are in the global namespace?

Comment: that worked for me too. I had to remember to run "clean" to make the error go away